# Improving long selenium search

Tags: python, performance, selenium

I am performing a selenium search for 1200 products on the web. Each product has 4 product codes to search on average, and I gotta perform the search on 3 different websites. The problem is that it takes too long and around 2/3 of the search it stop doing anything... so I have to abort the program. I manly use search elements using `find_elements(By.XPATH, path)` Is there any trick you could advise me to do in order to being able to complete the search? I dont' know whether it is because the program get its allocated memory full (which I guess if so it should throw an Exception... which it doesn't) or why it stop searching on the web.
I am using a Firefox driver.

P.S. The program runs for more than an hour.

Comment: Could you please clarify this: "The problem is that it takes too long and around 2/3 of the search it stop doing anything..."

Comment: I mean that after a while (just passed the half search) it performs no searches anymore. The program doesn't crash, but you can see that the driver doesnt perform any search anymore. To be clearer you can see that the mozilla window stays still and doesnt do anything more.

Comment: But not necessarily is a problem of your code, maybe it is a problem on the server-side. Justs some ideas: 1. Any blocking strategy in the server? 2. You find any useful information on the browser console?

Comment: NO useful information on the bugging console and when I run the program on a smaller data set (let's say using only 40 products) it works perfectly. The problem seems to occur when it is done looking for products in the first 2 websites and it goes visit the last one.

Comment: What if you close and open the browser each 40 products.

Comment: I would get a Max Try error from that webpage as i d be making too many requests in too short time. I tried adding some delay but that didnt work either. P.S then that was just a short test... As i said i gotta do it for 1200 products